# python mysql /mariaDB database error (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to run a long run query in MariaDB. and it`s always error in 5 minutes (300 second), throwing this error (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query').
but if my query is run directly in the database there is no timeout error.

I've read other similar topics on forums but nothing works

MariaDB is set with :

```
('connect_timeout', '36000')
('delayed_insert_timeout', '3600')
('idle_readonly_transaction_timeout', '0')
('idle_transaction_timeout', '0')
('idle_write_transaction_timeout', '0')
('innodb_flush_log_at_timeout', '1')
('innodb_lock_wait_timeout', '36000')
('innodb_rollback_on_timeout', 'OFF')
('interactive_timeout', '28800')
('lock_wait_timeout', '86400')
('net_read_timeout', '3600')
('net_write_timeout', '3600')
('rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout', '10000')
('rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout', '5')
('slave_net_timeout', '3600')
('thread_pool_idle_timeout', '3600')
('wait_timeout', '36000')
('max_allowed_packet', '1073741824')
('slave_max_allowed_packet', '1073741824')
```

it can be simulated using this simple code :

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

load_dotenv()

engine = create_engine(os.getenv('mysqlConn'), connect_args={'connect_timeout': 3600,'read_timeout': 3600,'write_timeout': 3600})

qry = ''' 
select SLEEP(310);
'''
records  = engine.execute(qry)
```

is there anything else that must be set so that this error does not occur?

Comment: What environment is it running? Normally no configuration is required to change for a 5 minute query. Is the server crashing for some reason? If so check its logs.

Comment: i run it on ubuntu using python 3.9 from anaconda. mariadb version 10.5.15.
There are no errors on the server, and the query finishes in mariadb (since I didn't set rollback) but in python it always gives a lost connection error.
Running the same query from dbeaver never gives an error, so I don't think it's the server's fault.
And if I run the query from python as long as it doesn't run for more than 300 seconds, it runs perfectly

Comment: Looks like a client side timeout, so this may help to re-configure that setting?

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-database-connection/#h-change-mysql-connection-timeout-from-python

Comment: yes, looks like client side timeout. but I haven't found a way how to solve it. I tried to run it using WSL (windows) on localhost, and it works fine. but on development server i still have that problem.